# How to hit two servlet in url in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I login one web application through url,after I wanted to jump one jsp or servlet through url.
how I directly go 2nd jsp page through url

Comment: my url is-http://172.128.11.156:8880/VFG/LoginAccess.jsp?userID=admin&password=password&userGroup=1                               but i directly jump to the :-  http://172.128.11.156:8880/VFG/AP_ReceiptsWisePaymentSummaryReportpdf.jsp?FromDate=28/10/2014&ToDate=28/10/2014&CostCentre=-1|ALL&ReportType=.pdf&collectionAgent=ALL&Summary=1

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, please add more details to help understand your problem.

Comment: Current code example please

Comment: what do you mean by jumping. its should either be called forwarding or redirecting.please correct the question

Comment: You seriously have a GET request with a URL containing `userID=admin&password=password` ? Ouch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all the solutions  ,

**1.** Use the **Filters** to intercept the URL through `web.xml`

**2.** Use the **Redirect** or **Forward** feature in `Servlets` or `Jsp`.

Comment: when i test with this HttpServletReponse.sendRedirect("http://172.128.11.156:8880/VFG/AP_ReceiptsWisePaymentSummaryReportpdf.jsp?FromDate=28/10/2014&ToDate=28/10/2014&CostCentre=-1|ALL&ReportType=.pdf&collectionAgent=ALL&Summary=1") then no output is given because this url is hit after login through this url http://172.128.11.156:8880/VFG/LoginAccess.jsp?userID=admin&password=password&userGroup=1

Answer (score 0):

user Servlet Filter Mapping in Web.xml:
Your web application may define several different filters with a specific purpose. Consider, you define two filters AuthenFilter and LogFilter. Rest of the process would remain as explained above except you need to create a different mapping as mentioned below:

Comment: <filter><filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name><filter-class>LogFilter</filter-class><init-param><param-name>test-param</param-name><param-value>Initia Paramter</param-value></init-param></filter><filter> <filter-name>AuthenFilter</filter-name><filter-class>AuthenFilter</filter-class><init-param><param-name>test-param</param-name><param-value>Initialization Paramter</param-value></init-param></filter><filter-mapping><filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping><filter-mapping><filter-name>AuthenFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>

Comment: also use Filters Application Order: <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>AuthenFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Comment: I have no permission to edit or view code  modify the code. only go to the 2nd url in one operation

Answer (score 0):

As with a servlet, there are two ways to do this. HttpServletReponse.sendRedirect() actually sends a response to the browser giving it a URL to fetch instead of the original one, which may be on a different server. The other option is to use a RequestDispatcher to load a different resource on the server instead of the resource which would have been loaded, transparently to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

useful examples for this, so I'm reduced to writing my own code. SecureFilter checks the current session to see whether there is a User object; if not, it forwards the request to a login form. While hardly a robust component, you can see how a more useful system could be implemented.

```
if (authorized) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
} else if (filterConfig != null) {
    String login_page = filterConfig.getInitParameter("login_page");
    if (login_page != null && !"".equals(login_page)) {
        filterConfig.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(login_page).
forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
}

throw new ServletException
("Unauthorized access, unable to forward to login page");
```

}